# As3 hittesting doesn't really work (nested)

Tags: actionscript-3, nested, collision, movieclip, hittest

I got a tank.

I got a hero (controllable character).

The tank has a nested movieclip which has a very thin surface area.

Yet, the thing detects a collision when it's not even touching the hero.

```
public class tank_sight extends MovieClip
{
    private var _root:MovieClip;

    public function tank_sight() 
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED, beginClass);
    }

    private function beginClass(event:Event):void
    {
        _root = MovieClip(root);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
    }

    private function loop(event:Event):void
    {
        if(this.hitTestObject(_root.hero.hitbox))
        {
            this.gotoAndStop(2);
            trace("HIT");
            fire();
        }
        else
        {
            this.gotoAndStop(1);
        }
    }

    private function fire():void
    {
        var shell:Shell = new Shell(x, y, rotation - 180);
        _root.addChild(shell);
    }
}
```

What's wrong? I don't get it.

EDIT: Sight is rotating, so that's probably why. I tried using this code on the player class:

```
    point = _root.tanks.barrel.sight.localToGlobal(new Point());

        if(this.hitTestPoint(point.x, point.y, false))
                {
                    trace("HIT");
                }
```

But it doesn't work.. It never traces "HIT", unless I stand in some weird location at certain times.

Answer (score 0):

`hitTestObject` works with nested objects also (display objects that have different parents), you should check logic of your game, and do some tests.

Simple example:

```
var squareHolder:Sprite = new Sprite();
var squareInner:Shape = new Shape();
var hitHolder:Sprite = new Sprite();
var hitCircle:Shape = new Shape();

hitCircle.graphics.beginFill(0x990000);
hitCircle.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 20);

squareInner.graphics.beginFill(0x009900);
squareInner.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 40, 40);

addChild(squareHolder);
squareHolder.addChild(squareInner);
squareHolder.x = 200;
squareHolder.y = 100;
squareInner.x = 50;
squareInner.y = 50;

stage.addChild(hitHolder);
hitHolder.addChild(hitCircle);
hitCircle.transform.matrix = new Matrix(1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 30, 30);

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, function (e:MouseEvent):void {
    hitHolder.x = e.stageX;
    hitHolder.y = e.stageY;

    if (hitCircle.hitTestObject(squareInner)) {
        trace("Ding!");
    }
});
```

Whatever you do with `hitCircle` (visible=false, trasparent fill, transformations) it will still work.

Comment: When you mean the logic of my game, what o you exactly mean? I can't figure out what's wrong with the code I made.. it should work!